# Error Xamarin Forms System.Numerics.Vectors

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

El problema que tengo es que cuando ejecuto la el emulador me dice que se han encontrado conflictos entre distintas versiones de System.Numerics.Vectors que no se han podido resolver un coque entre la version 2.0.5.0 y la version 4.1.3.0

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.